# Can I accessing variables which is declare in say class A from say class B in Java

Tags: java, class, variables, dot-operator

I am a newbie in Java. I have done a sample program that is finding the area of a rectangle. The code is below.

```
package rectangle;

public class Rectangle {
    int length, width;

    int rectArea() {
        int area = length * width;
        return (area);
    }
}

class RectArea {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int area1;

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle();

        rect.length = 14;
        rect.width = 13;
        area1 = rect.rectArea();

        System.out.println("Area1=" + area1);
    }
}
```

In the above code `length` and `width` are variables which declare in class `Rectangle`. Now `area` is also a variable which holds the data `length * width` and this `area`variable is also declared in class `Rectangle`

We can access `length` and `width` variables from another class named `RectArea` by using the dot operator. But why can't we access `area` variable which is declared in `Rectangle` class from the `RectArea` class (using dot operator) directly to evaluate the value of `Rectangle`?

That is, why we can't use the below code to evaluate the value of a newly created object `rect1` from `RectArea` class.

```
area1 = rect1.area;
System.out.println("Area1="+ area1);
```

Or why can't we access the `area` variable which is declared in `Rectangle` class from `RectArea` class using the above code?

Comment: because that is a local variable inside a method, it doesn't exist on scope of the class. Neither should you expose your other variables like that. You should declare them private, and restrict access through getters and setters

Comment: `rect1` has no field called `area`. therefore you cant access it

Comment: what is `rect.area` supposed to be? `rect` is a `Rectangle` which does not have an `area`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

area is not the class level variable. Its a local variable in rectArea method, thus, it will not be visible outside the method and won't be accessible via dot operator like class variables

Comment: what if I declare the area variable as static

Comment: you cannot declare a static variable inside a method. static variables are declared at class level only

Comment: But I can declare a method as static if i declare the method as static what will happen.

Comment: Still you won't be able to access the variables which are local to a method neither you would be able to declare local variables as static.

Comment: @coding_ninza that is because methods are declared at class level. You won't find a method declared inside a method.

Comment: If I declare the area outside the method means if I declare the area in the class only can I use it in that way.

Comment: Yes, provided you have proper access specifier for it.

Answer (score 1):

**area** is not class variable, it is inside method and you can not access method variable as these are local and visible to method only.

Answer (score 1):

There are local variables and instance (class) variables. The class variables are like length and width and they can be used within the whole class.

But with local variables they can only be used within the method/block of code where you have declared them. In this case area is declared in the method and is only available in the method.

Once the code jumps out of the method (return ) area no longer exists.

I have fixed the code below so that it does work:

```
    int length, width, area;

        void getData(int x, int y)
        {
            length=x;
            width=y;
        }

        int rectArea()
        {
            area=length*width;
            return area;

        }

        }
        class RectArea{

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                int area1, area2;

                 Rectangle  rect1 =new Rectangle();

                 Rectangle rect2 =new Rectangle();

                rect1.length=14;
                rect1.width=13;
                area1=rect1.length*rect1.width;
                rect2.getData(13,14);
                area2=rect2.rectArea();

          System.out.println("Area1="+ area1);
          System.out.println("Area1="+ area2);
System.out.println("Area1="+ rect2.area);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Java doesn't have global variables, what you mean is the distinction between local variables (method/block-scope) and instance or static variables (class scope)

Comment: Thanks, I edit my answer!

Answer (score 0):

*area* is a local variable of the method *rectArea*. It is not accessible outside the class or even inside the class, except for the same method.

If you want *area* to be accessible outside, why don't you try something like this:

```
public class Rectangle {

    int length, width, area;

    void getData(int x, int y) {
        length = x;
        width = y;
        area = length * width;
    }
}
```